# Is there a way to get the "base URL" for a Controller in Spring when testing?

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I have a controller class that looks something like this:

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("controller")
public class Controller {
    @RequestMapping("foo")
    public String method() {
        return "foo'd the bar";
    }
}
```

My test looks like so:

```java
@WebMvcTest(Controller.class)
public class ControllerTest {
    @Autowired
    private Controller controller;

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Test
    public void canCreate() throws Exception {
        Assertions.assertThat(controller).isNotNull();
    }

    @Test
    public void canGetDummy() throws Exception {
        this.mockMvc.perform(get("/controller/foo")).andDo(print()).andExpect(status().isOk());
    }
}
```

This seems a bit fragile to me, with the "base URL" for the controller hardcoded in at least `n+1` places for `n` methods tested. Is there a way to configure the test to avoid this (so I would write `/foo` instead of `/controller/foo`)? I could use a static variable, but it seems like there should be a cleaner solution.

(Or am I thinking about this wrong, and having to write the full path is good - and in that case, why?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The full path `/controller/foo` is part of the Web API that you're testing. You can extract the string parts to constants if you like, but including it directly in the tests one way or the other is a Good Thing.